# Listing first n files in a working directory

Tags: r

I am aware that this is probably a very simple question, but I have scoured the web for an answer and haven't found one yet.
I'm a beginner at R, and want to list the first 900 files in my working directory - the beginning of my code looks like this

```
setwd("...")
my.files_x = list.files(pattern = ".txt")
```

how would I specify that I only want the first n files listed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `my.files_x = list.files(pattern = ".txt")[1:900]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to working with paths I like to work with the fs-package and tidyverse:

```
library(fs)
library(tidyverse)

fs::dir_info() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(str_detect(path, ".txt")) %>% 
  head(900)
```

The advantage also lies in the fact that further information on the files is available and can be further processed.

Answer (score 0):

please see https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-accessors-explained/
you can call first 900 rows with data[1:900] if you have severals columns you can use data[rows,columns] for example data[2,1:900] this is row 2 columns 1 to 900